# Characterizing earthquakes using accelerometer data

Tags: earthquakes, measurements, instrumentation

Is there a way to use accelerometer data to characterize earthquake intensity, e.g., on Richter scale?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, you can measure seismic energy with accelerometers. Most people do.**

There are three ways to measure seismic energy: by displacement $x$, velocity $\dot{x}$, or acceleration $\ddot{x}$. Loose-spring devices like [geophones](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2011/7/15/geophysical-stamps-3-geophone.html) measure velocity; stiff-spring devices like [MEMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems) and [relative gravimeters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimeter) measure acceleration: they are accelerometers. Those used in seismology and exploration geophysics are very precise.

I wrote about the various instruments used to measure seismic energy in [a blog post](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2011/7/15/geophysical-stamps-3-geophone.html) a while back. An excerpt about seismometers:

> Seismometers [are] precision instruments not used in exploration
>   seismology because they are usually quite bulky and require careful
>   set-up and calibration. [Most modern models] are accelerometers, much
>   like relative gravimeters, measuring ground acceleration from the
>   force on a proof mass. Seismometers can detect frequencies in a very
>   broad band, on the order of 0.001 Hz to 500 Hz: that's 19 octaves!

Short story: When digital seismic receivers arrived on the scene in Calgary in the early 2000s, there was a lot of skepticism. We spent a lot of time comparing them to traditional geophones. The conclusion: they were about the same. [Here's one comparison](http://www.crewes.org/ResearchLinks/GraduateTheses/2008/Hons-MSc-2008.pdf) by Michael Hons at CREWES, and [here's another](http://www.searchanddiscovery.com/pdfz/abstracts/pdf/2013/90170cspg/abstracts/ndx_hons.pdf.html); [here's yet another](http://www.sercel.com/products/Lists/ProductPublication/Sercel-digital-geophone.pdf) from one of the big manufacturers, Sercel (now CGG). Finally, [here's a presentation](http://www.iris.edu/hq/instrumentation_meeting/files/pdfs/MEMS_Seismology.pdf) more oriented around earthquake seismology.

**Okay, but I was talking about the accelerometers in iPhones!**

Oh, sorry. As @Fred points out in his answer, consumer-grade MEMS accelerometers (as you might find in a phone or latop) may not have the sensitivity or calibration that a researcher would want, but one might compensate somewhat for this with multiple measurements, e.g. an array of devices. In other words: quantity, not quality. (This is perfectly legit: we do it in exploration seismics too.)

[Dashti et al. (2013)](http://bayen.eecs.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/journals/15WCEE_iShake.pdf) in *Earthquake Spectra Journal* found you could get useful measurements (e.g. for emergency response) from networks of phones with a few tricks:

- The more measurements the better.
- Horizontal orientation is best.
- Prefer high-friction phone covers.
- Don't expect to get great data for small quakes.
- Treat small groups of phones as arrays.
- Don't use data for phones that fell off a table!

Answer (score 3):

It appears the issue with using accelerometers for characterizing earthquake intensity is their lack of sensitivity, as you can read from the [live science](http://www.livescience.com/30656-detect-earthquake-with-home-computer.html) website.

But that does not mean that accelerometers can't provide useful information about earthquakes, particularly larger quakes. Stanford University has established the [Quake-Catcher Network](http://qcn.stanford.edu/) to provide it with earthquake information from accelerometers in people laptops and other devices. More information about this can be found at their other [web page](http://qcn.stanford.edu/sensor/).

Comment: I think you need to clarify that you are talking about a particular type of accelerometer and/or device.