# Using an accelerometer as a geophone to conduct a seismic survey

Tags: seismology, seismic

I am doing a capstone project for a sensor systems course and I would like to write  a python program to acquire, process and present seismic data like that of seismic surveys. Is it possible using just an Arduino and an accelerometer?

I have access to the following accelerometer:

SparkFun Triple Axis Accelerometer Breakout - MMA8452Q

Comment: If you don't get an answer here try SE Engineering.

Comment: See also https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/using-accelerometer-as-a-seismograph and https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4681/70

Answer (score 1):

Accelerometers have already been used for acquiring seismic data in a lot of studies: see [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6679216/), and references therein.

As for the code part, there is a Python framework for seismology: [ObsPy](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki).